# Python - Cannot join thread - No multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have this piece of code in my program. Where OnDone function is an event in a wxPython GUI. When I click the button DONE, the OnDone event fires up, which then does some functionality and starts the thread self.tstart - with target function StartEnable. This thread I want to join back using self.tStart.join(). However I am getting an error as follows:

```
Exception in thread StartEnablingThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "//wagnernt.wagnerspraytech.com/users$/kundemj/windows/my documents/Production GUI/Trial python Codes/GUI_withClass.py", line 638, in StartEnable
    self.tStart.join()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 931, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
RuntimeError: cannot join current thread
```

I have not got this type of error before. Could any one of you guys tell me what I am missing here.

```
    def OnDone(self, event):
        self.WriteToController([0x04],'GuiMsgIn')
        self.status_text.SetLabel('PRESSURE CALIBRATION DONE \n DUMP PRESSURE')
        self.led1.SetBackgroundColour('GREY')
        self.add_pressure.Disable()
        self.tStart = threading.Thread(target=self.StartEnable, name = "StartEnablingThread", args=())
        self.tStart.start()

    def StartEnable(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            if int(self.pressure_text_control.GetValue()) < 50:
                print "HELLO"
                self.start.Enable()
                self.tStart.join()
                print "hello2"
                break
```

I want to join the thread after the "if" condition has executed. Until them I want the thread to run.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Joining Is Waiting

*Joining* a thread actually means waiting fo another thread to finish.

So, in `thread1`, there can be code which says:

```
thread2.join()
```

That means *"stop here and do not execute the next line of code until `thread2` is finished"*.

If you did (in `thread1`) the following, that would fail with the error from the question:

```
thread1.join()    # RuntimeError: cannot join current thread
```

### Joining Is Not Stopping

Calling `thread2.join()` does not cause `thread2` to stop, nor even signal to it in any way that it should stop.

A thread stops when its target function exits. Often, a thread is implemented as a loop which checks for a signal (a variable) which tells it to stop, e.g.

```
def run():
    while whatever:
        # ...
        if self.should_abort_immediately:
            print 'aborting'
            return
```

Then, the way to stop the thread is to do:

```
thread2.should_abort_immediately = True  # tell the thread to stop
thread2.join()  # entirely optional: wait until it stops
```

## The Code from the Question

That code already implements the stopping correctly with the `break`. The `join` should just be deleted.

```
        if int(self.pressure_text_control.GetValue()) < 50:
            print "HELLO"
            self.start.Enable()
            print "hello2"
            break
```

Comment: Thank you Zvone, great answer. I just have one followup question:

Comment: Thank you Zvone, great answer. I just have one follow-up question: I start a thread in a python file whose target function is in a different python file. Where should I declare the should_abort_immediately? Should I do it is a global variable in my first file or in the second file? Eventually, I would like to stop the thread from the first python file.

Comment: @JeshKundem I usually make a class (inherited from `Thread`) for every thread. That way it is easier to keep track of what code is executed in which thread. Having the thread in a separate file is perfect. The variable should definitely be in the thread's code. I like having also a `stop(self)` method in the thread which sets the variable and then `join`s. Then you just call that from the outside.

Comment: You definitely answered the question, but I am unable to figure out how you return the thread target function by setting a variable from outside. I am still banging my head over it. You can find an example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921570/python-threading-making-the-thread-function-return-from-an-external-signal

Comment: @JeshKundem I gave you an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39926065/389289

Comment: Really nice description. I've never fully understood how thread.join() should be used until now

Answer (score 1):

When the `StartEnable` method is executing, it is running on the *StartEnablingThread* you created in the `__init__` method. You cannot join the current thread. This is clearly stated in the documentation for the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) call.

> join() raises a RuntimeError if an attempt is made to join the current thread as that would cause a deadlock. It is also an error to join() a thread before it has been started and attempts to do so raises the same exception.

Answer (score -10):

I have some bad news. Threading in Python is pointless and you best bet to look at using only 1 thread or use multi process. If you will need to look at thread then you will need to look at a different language like C# or C.  Have look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

The reason that threading is pointless in python is because of the global interpreter lock (GIL). This make you only able to use one thread at a time, so no multi-threading in python but there are people working on it. http://pypy.org/

Comment: Threading in Python is not pointless. It has its limitations, but it is still in many situations better than multiprocessing.

Comment: Threading is not limitation it just cannot really be done. As you only able to use one thread at a time. You just keep on moving from one thread to the other and not ran them at the same time like want threads should do. look up what the global interpreter lock does.

Comment: Hmmm... would you also say that threads can't be used on CPU with only one core? Or processes, for that matter, because one CPU core can only run one thing at a time...

Comment: Yes and No. Anyway it the run-time is the problem. It is done to make sure it able fully be able to access and used C language function without any problem occurring be the use of threads. As it say on pyhton site : "CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe. (However, since the GIL exists, other features have grown to depend on the guarantees that it enforces.)"  In other word it stop threading from working.

Comment: "because one CPU core can only run one thing at a time" is was true on the old CPU like Intel Pentium 3. The OS put each thread in a queue and giving amount of time to run in turn when there turn is over and still need to run then added back into a queue. It make look like you run more then one program at the same time. have look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing) @zvone

Comment: Don't confuse threading with parallel processing. Threading allows a piece of code that is waiting for something to yield processor time to another piece of code. It makes no guarantee of those two threads being able to run concurrently, it only gives that appearance if the threads are switching quickly enough.

Comment: @TWReever I think you are confuse or not fully understand what threading is. Threading and Parallel Processing are same-thing. Also CPU may have more then one core and each core can have one or more thread running on it them same time (e.g. concurrently).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

Comment: @CRAIGADAMS no, i think you are confused. From the article you quoted "Systems with a single processor generally implement multithreading by time slicing." You can absolutely have threads on a single core machine.

Comment: @TWReever You need to read it all, not just the top.  "You can absolutely have threads on a single core machine" yes this is true but most CPU are not single core now a days.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcoVYfDVEww

Comment: It also say in the articte "Multithreading can also be applied to one process to enable parallel execution on a multiprocessing system." and " Multiple threads can exist within one process, executing concurrently and sharing resources such as memory", Also do see that youtube link.  youtube.com/watch?v=VcoVYfDVEww

Comment: I did read the entire thing, and I still stand by my original point. Threads have been around long before multicore processors, and were first used as a way to timeshare the CPU and allow it to give the impression of being able to perform multiple tasks at once by constantly switching between running threads. Parallel processing takes advantage of running multiple threads **simultaneously** on multiple cores. Many CPUs will still run threads from a single process on the same core unless explicitly instructed to run it on another one.

Comment: The bottom line is that threading in Python is not pointless as you suggested. It can be used the same way it is in any other language that provides a threading mechanism, ie. for a task to yield CPU time when it is waiting for a resource, etc. I do agree that it is limited as you mentioned by the GIL, and doesn't allow you to run things on multiple cores, however, as @zvone stated, it uses in many applications.

Comment: Yes but on python you cannot run any threads concurrently because of the global interpreter lock (GIL), unless it IronPython as does not have global interpreter lock (GIL). You have to agree on that. (: This what make threading next door to pointless on python unless you ok with a timeshare system.

Comment: It is only useful for IO