# Python Threading: Making the thread function return from an external signal

Tags: python, multithreading, time

Could anyone please point out whats wrong with this code. I am trying to return the thread through a variable flag, which I want to control in my main thread.

## test27.py

```
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

def Read(x,y):
    flag = 1
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            z = x+y; w = x-y
            print z*w
            time.sleep(1)
            if flag == 0:
                print "ABORTING"
                return
        finally:
            print " SINGLE run of thread executed"
            lock.release()
```

## test28.py

```
import time, threading

from test27 import Read

print "Hello Welcome"
a = 2; b = 5
t = threading.Thread(target = Read, name = 'Example Thread', args = (a,b))
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
t.flag = 0 # This is not updating the flag variable in Read FUNCTION
t.join() # Because of the above command I am unable to wait until the thread finishes. It is blocking.
print "PROGRAM ENDED"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Thread` class can be instantiated with the `target` argument. Then you just give it a function which should be executed in a new thread. It is a convenient way to start a simple thread, but for more control it is usually easier to have a class inherited from `Thread`, which has additional member variables, like the `flag` for aborting.

For example:

```
import time
import threading

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        # or in Python 2:
        # super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._stop_requested = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop_requested:
            z = self.x + self.y
            w = self.x - self.y
            print (z * w)
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self, timeout=None):
        self._stop_requested = True
        self.join(timeout)
```

Then, to start the thread, call `start()` and then to stop it call `stop()`:

```
>>> def run_thread_for_5_seconds():
...     t = MyThread(3, 4)
...     t.start()
...     time.sleep(5)
...     t.stop()
...
>>> run_thread_for_5_seconds()
-7
-7
-7
-7
-7
>>>
```

Comment: While this will work for a simple example, using unsafe thread messaging will blow in your face in a real application. `"If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event."` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: For further reading I suggest to look up a problem known as "race condition"

Comment: @Muposat This thread is non-daemonic, because [daemon defaults to False](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon). Assignment `self._stop_requested = True` is thread-safe. Attribute `_stop_requested` is written only from the main thread, exactly once before the thread is started and exactly once while it is running. If you see a race condition here, please explain how it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Regular variables should not be tracked in threads. This is done to prevent race condition. You must use thread-safe constructs to communicate between threads. For a simple flag use `threading.Event`. Also you cannot access local variable `flag` via thread object. It is local, and is only visible from scope. You must either use a global variable, as in my example below or create an Object before calling your thread and use a member variable.

```
from threading import Event
flag = Event()

def Read(x,y):
    global flag
    flag.clear()
    ...
    if flag.is_set():
        return
```

main thread:

```
sleep(5)
flag.set()
```

P.S.: I just noticed that you attempted to use lock() in the thread, but failed to use it in the main thread. For a simple flag go with Event. For a lock() you need to lock both parts and mitigate a risk of a deadlock.

Comment: I am unable to understand your answer. I tried reading it Could you please explain in beginner terms. I edited my question, like exactly how I am doing it and how I want it, The code works once in a while. I have not defined a global variable as flag.

Comment: Beginner version: 1. you cannot access ``flag`` outside of ``Read``. 2. You use ``lock`` incorrectly; should use Event instead. Just copy this example: http://itsjustsosimple.blogspot.com/2014/01/python-thread-synchronization-using.html

Comment: I defined flag as global as you mentioned and still cant access it. flag.set() is giving me an error

Comment: NameError: name 'flag' is not defined -- Happens at flag.set() in my test28.py. Regarding the lock. Am I using it right in my updated code.

Comment: Flag error is probably because you split code in two files. You now need to import flag from test27. I am only guessing because you did not show me new code. As far as lock: you did not lock access to flag in test28, so you are not using it correctly.